# need a formula to compare one constant cell with other cells and return a value from third cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function

column a      _          _______ column B

1  amount   ________    _     reduction

2_  1000
3_   750    ______________        100
4_   500______________            200
5_   250______________            300
6_   1300_____________       -100

difference  _       ______reduction amount

```
    <250_                 _0
    >=250<500_         _   100
    >=500<750_          _  200
    >=750<1000_         _  300


    Compare a2 to a3 and return reduction amount to b3 based on difference.
```

then compare a4 to a2 and return reduction amount to b4 and so on. If difference is negative

than   reduction should be negative

I Have tried using if/and functions but have not had much luck would i be better off using some sort of table.  I have watched if function videos and looked all through help on excel but just can't figure this out.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your ranges aren't consistent and what you're trying to accomplish isn't clear.  It would help to edit your question to show how the cell references relate to the tables, and provide an example that covers the different conditions.

Comment: You can nest IF formula's. I'd write down the if formulas in a few cells and then merge everything together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your Data starting A2=1000, A3=750... and your Reduction array in I1=0 J1=0, I2=250 J2=100, I3=500 J3=200 etc like this using these values:
I   J
0   0
250 100
500 200
750 300

Then in B3 =IF($A$2-A3>0,VLOOKUP($A$2-A3,$I$1:$J$4,2), - VLOOKUP(ABS($A$2-A3),$I$1:$J$4,2)) and you can drag it down